# Timely interval to retrieve data from db, and stop when the data arrives

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, logic

I'm a newbie, so be kind :)

What is the simplest solution for checking for, retrieving and using newly received data from a mysql database?

The database is being updated from an external api. Ideally I would get it as it arrives but using intervals could work too. 
On the first iteration and then once every 5 minutes if there is no new data meanwhile - do an action with the next entry of the array which might cause data to be updated within the next 5 min. But I want to make sure to stop everything if the new data has been received, and just perform some stuff in php.

what's the most simple solution? php vs jquery/ajax?

my proposed solution is in jquery:

```
        <script>
            var newdata = false;
            if(newdata === false){
                setTimeout (function(){
                    $.each(array, function(){
                            $.post('checkdb.php',data,function(resp){
                                          if(resp){
                                          newdata=resp;
                                          return newdata;                                                  
                                          }
                                          else{
                                          $.post('doaction.php',data);
                                          // cause a potential update within the next 5 min
                                          }
                            });
                    });
                }, 300000); 
            }
            else{
                // move newdata back to php and (then) do something with response
            }
        </script>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You should not put semicolons after blocks. It doesn't make sense to wrap everything in a PHP tags, either (JavaScript is not PHP at all).

Comment: Ok thanks! will fix the ;. Regarding the php tag: I know, but this is part of a php page (that's where all the variables come from), if you can suggest a pure php solution that's great too. tnx

Comment: okay, i fixed both, tnx! any comments on the logic would be appreciated too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution in the end is indeed in php and not ajax (there is really no need for client side in this situation).

Here's the outline:

```
    <?php
        while (something is true){
            //do stuff

            flush(); // execute the stuff you did until now
            sleep(300); // wait 5 min
            // now check database and retrieve new data, if any, and insert into $result 

            if (isset($result)){
                //do stuff with the $result
                break; // get out of the loop
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use such logic on client side. JavaScript could be easily manipulated/changed. Someone could replace the interval with much shorter one and stress the server. Read about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), use it for waiting for the results from the server. On the server side do all the logic: implement database polling (with interval, as you wish), and, when needed, push the data to the browser/stop polling/do whatever you want.

Comment: okay this sounds like the direction i should take, thanks. but how do i use intervals in php? i couldn't figure it out

Comment: Well it depends of course what really you are trying to achieve. You can use PHP sleep() function to trigger action in a loop within the request timeout. When the timeout is reached, JavaScript should initiate another request. You can also read about PHP sockets.

Comment: Also, you can use a comet server or node.js. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: in php it is by using "sleep"? but why the js at all? as far as i can see, the only reason i am using js, is for the timeout function. all the rest is basically logic+variables from php. so if the time would be in php too, then is there still need for js here?

Comment: Yes, because still something has to pull the data from the server. PHP on its own can't send anything. You have to request it - either by using refresh button in the browser, or AJAX/Comet.